# Unable to mount location after installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, mount, hard-disk

I have been using Ubuntu for a while, but I decided to move to Linux Mint. I removed everything and clearly installed it. After the installation there are two parts which are `File System` and `Toshiba`. When I try to open Toshiba it says unable to mount location. Output of `sudo fdisk -l` can be seen below. By the way I have only one HDD (Toshiba).Moreover I shared two pics to be more clear:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8cecb72c

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1435547647   717772800   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1435547648  1465147391    14799872   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that's probably your SWAP partition. Can you access the "file System" drive?

Comment: yeah I can access it without any problems. I am just curious about if it is a corrupted block or not

Answer (score 2):

I think that this 'Toshisba' icon represents graphically a whole drive as a device just like /dev/sda. Device cannot be mounted this way. Only partition formatted with filesystem which is represented in your case as 'File System' icon. I suggest to ignore it or maybe there is some setting in a filemanager to hide it.

Comment: Oh I just saw your reply now. Some block of HDD could not be corrupted right ? By the way, I think it might refer to `swap` area but I am not sure. I created swap area as primary not logical.

Comment: A swap partition can be primary or logical -- it doesn't matter. Swap isn't a real filesystem, it's rather memory-like structure prepared to manage memory pages. If you are not sure you can use "swapoff -a" command as a root user. It will switch off all swaps you currently have. Then check if you can still see that 'Toshiba' icon. 'swapon -a' will enable all swaps back.

Comment: nope it didnt work

Comment: So it's not a swap just probably as I wrote - entire disk device representation. Entire disks cannot be mounted, just partitions, so I think everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Go into menu and search disks.
If you see that your partition is free and not initialized or created
just click on plus sign and create it.
Then you will see a play button beside the plus sign when the has been partition created. Just click on it and your partition will be mounted.